# Reloading the page on back button click works in debug mode only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, onbeforeunload

I am reloading the current aspx page on browser's back button click.

I have got the below code which works in IE11.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {   
    if (window.event) {          
        if (window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0) {// Back button/IE   
            window.location.href = window.location.href; // not using window.location.reload() as I dont want to submit the form
        }   
    } 
};
```

This works fine but I am getting a strange behavior here. When I add debugger inside window.onbeforeunload and debug the code, it reloads the current page successfully instead of going back to previous page. But when I run it normally (without adding debugger), it wont work.

I tried adding timeout as well

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = window.location.href; }, 3000);
```

but this also doesn't work.

I searched for some of the ways like `e.preventDefault()` while submitting the form but none of them seems to be applicable here.

Anyone has idea how can I fix this issue or any alternative way to achieve this?